# In this context, can I say:"They drank two bottles"?

Tags: phrase-usage

teachers.

Normally, The amount of a bottle of wine is 750ml.

Yesterday, My friends drank 1500ml from the barrel,

can I say:

***That means they drank two bottles yesterday.***

Here, "two bottles" still means the wine, right?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

I think everyone would understand the sentiment, but it would be more precise to say:

> That means they drank two bottles worth of wine yesterday.

or

> That means they drank the equivalent of two bottles yesterday.

Comment: Those are *exactly* the two "preferred alternatives" I was going to post in a comment! I suspect the "equivalent" version can be used in a wider variety of contexts, but the "worth" version strikes me as particularly idiomatic for OP's specific context.

Comment: Thanks so much!!!I think it is like changing the unit. Like I put a bowl of a rice on a plate. I ate all the rice. Can I say: I still ate one bowl?  And "bowl" here means the rice, not just number, am I right?

Comment: Yes, "changing the unit" is a good way of putting it! Notice that for "bowl of rice", the central noun is **bowl**, which is why it's acceptable to use it as the "unit". Moreover, they _were_ actually eating from a bowl. But in your example with wine, bottles were never actually involved.

Answer (score 0):

A good answer has already been given, I also would add:

> That means they had two bottles [of wine] yesterday.

although it slightly shifts emphasis from the volume to the mere fact they had wine. I am not sure of the latter statement, so a native speaker's help would be appreciated.